# How to plot bar graph to compare two quantities on y-axis at specific values on x-axis?

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I have the following matrix with two rows, each representing a different quantity.

```
y=[10 35 45; 
   60 70 80];
```

I want a bar graph for each row at specified values of `x` which are `25`, `50` and `75` i.e. I want to plot `10` and `60` (y-axis) against `25` (on x-axis), `35` and `70` (y-axis) against `50` (x-axis) and `45` and `80` (y-axis) against `75` (x-axis).

I have used:

```
bar (y)
```

But this doesn't allow me to specify values on x-axis. Moreover I've also tried:

```
bar(x,y);
```

but I get the following error:

> "The length of `X` must match the number of rows of `Y`"

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. There are some questions of yours that haven't marked as accepted and no clarification of yours whether those work or not. Consider marking the  answers that solve your problem as accepted and/or upvoting the helpful answers of your previous questions as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need transposed `y` to match the dimensions of `x`.

```
bar(x, y.');
```

[image: output]